# MediaPlayer.createVolumeShaper throws an IllegalArgumentException: invalid configuration or operation: -19

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When using the new VolumeShaper in Android O, I am attempting to create it with a MediaPlayer:

```
// Create a VolumeShaper configuration
VolumeShaper.Configuration volumeShaperConfig =
    new VolumeShaper.Configuration.Builder()
                    .setDuration(3000)
                    .setCurve(new float[] {0.f, 1.f}, new float[] {0.f, 1.f})
                    .setInterpolatorType(VolumeShaper.Configuration.INTERPOLATOR_TYPE_LINEAR)
                    .build();
mVolumeShaper = mMediaPlayer.createVolumeShaper(configuration);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

When I try to run it, however, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid configuration or operation: -19
   at android.media.VolumeShaper.applyPlayer(VolumeShaper.java:189)
   at android.media.VolumeShaper.<init>(VolumeShaper.java:54)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.createVolumeShaper(MediaPlayer.java:1392)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a `VolumeShaper`, the `MediaPlayer` object has to be in the "Initialized" state, which happens after calling `setDataSource` on it. (See: [MediaPlayer state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram).)

In this case it's as simple as changing the code to do it in this order:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mVolumeShaper = mMediaPlayer.createVolumeShaper(configuration);
```

It's also possible to delay the creation of VolumeShaper until calling `.start()` on the `MediaPlayer`, and it's worth noting that, with the configuration above, the volume will start off muted, so you'll need to apply the `VolumeShaper` when starting to play or the output will be silent.

To do this, just use this:

```
public void play() {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    mVolumeShaper.apply(VolumeShaper.Operation.PLAY);
}
```

To mute it, before pausing or as the track is ending, just apply it in reverse, like this:

```
public void setMuted(boolean muted) {
    if (muted) {
        mVolumeShaper.apply(VolumeShaper.Operation.REVERSE);
    } else {
        mVolumeShaper.apply(VolumeShaper.Operation.PLAY);
    }
}
```